# What is cardinal addition in absence of choice of two disjoint equal sized Dedekind infinite sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the proof in Zermelo, without using choice nor foundation, of the cardinality of the Boolean union of two equal sized disjoint Dedekind infinite sets being equal to the cardinality of each one of them? Formally: $$ \forall A \forall B: A,B \text { are Ddk infinite} \land  A \cap B = \emptyset \land |A|=|B| \implies \\ |A \cup B| = |A|$$

Where: $$ A \text { is Ddk infinite } \iff \exists B \subsetneq A \exists f: A \to B, f \text { is an injection}$$

*(Follow-up question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4462737/what-is-the-cardinal-addition-of-two-disjoint-equal-sized-pure-dedkind-infinite).)*

Comment: Do you mean dually Dedekind infinite sets or weakly Dedekind infinite sets?

Comment: I don't think that statement is true without choice; consider two copies of $\mathbb{N}\sqcup A$, with $A$ an amorphous set.

Comment: @MathGeek, Dedekind infinite set is a set where there exists a proper subset of it and it injects into that proper subset.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I forgot to put the condition of disjointness so the uniting sets must be disjoint of each other.

Comment: @Zuhair That doesn't help: there's no bijection between $\mathbb{N}\sqcup A$ and $[(\mathbb{N}\sqcup A)\times\{0\}]\cup[(\mathbb{N}\sqcup A)\times\{1\})]$ if $A$ is amorphous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you're trying to prove is **false**.

Suppose $X$ is an amorphous set, WLOG disjoint from $\mathbb{N}$. Let $A=(\mathbb{N}\cup X)\times\{0\}$ and let $B=(\mathbb{N}\cup X)\times \{1\}$. Clearly $A\equiv B$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$. However, there is no injection (let alone bijection) from $A\cup B$ to $A$.

To see this, note that up to $\equiv$ we can rewrite $A$ as $\mathbb{N}\cup X$ and rewrite $A\cup B$ as $\mathbb{N}\sqcup X_0\sqcup X_1$ for amorphous sets $X_0,X_1$. Now any injective function $$f:\mathbb{N}\sqcup X_0\sqcup X_1\rightarrow\mathbb{N}\cup X$$ must send all-but-finitely-much of $X_0$ into $X$, and similarly must send all-but-finitely-much of $X_1$ into $X$. But then $f[X_0]$ and $f[X_1]$ are disjoint infinite subsets of $X$, contradicting amorphousness.

Comment: What if we require that each set is purely Dedekindian, that is every Tarski infinite subset of it is Dedekindian infinite also, would that make a change?

Comment: @Zuhair Yes, that would ruin this argument. But I don't have much experience with purely Dedekindian sets; I'd suggest asking that as a separate question.

Comment: I'll do! Thanks.