# What is the cardinal addition of two disjoint equal sized pure Dedkind infinite sets, in absence of choice, foundation, and replacement?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

This follows a [prior](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4462483/what-is-cardinal-addition-in-absence-of-choice-of-two-disjoint-equal-sized-dedek/4462729?noredirect=1#comment9350310_4462729) question:

What is the proof in Zermelo, without using choice nor foundation, of the cardinality of the Boolean union of two equal sized disjoint pure Dedekind infinite sets being equal to the cardinality of each one of them? Formally: $$ \forall A \forall B: A,B \text { are Ddk infinite} \land  A \cap B = \emptyset \land |A|=|B| \\\implies  |A \cup B| = |A|$$

Where: $$ A \text { is Ddk infinite } \iff \exists B \subsetneq A \exists f: A \to B, f \text { is injective}$$

Now, $$ A \text { is pure Ddk infinite } \iff \\\forall B \subseteq A (B \text { is Tarski infinite } \implies B \text { is Ddk infinite}) $$

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question?

Comment: Re: the phrasing of the first sentence, are you certain there *is* such a proof? Also, do you really mean Zermelo, or $\mathsf{ZF}-\mathsf{Reg}$ (that is, do you allow replacement)?

Comment: @MathGeek No - note the term "pure" here, and see the OP's comments to my answer to his previous question.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes I agree - my set theory isn't great and I'm sure this applies to others.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I'm not certain, but I would conjecture that. But I need the proof in Zermelo only, so Replacement is not allowed.

Comment: @Zuhair I've edited the title to clarify that. Without choice, regularity, or replacement, there's very little you can do. I strongly suspect that there is in fact no proof. Why do you conjecture that there is?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, well its a guess, but in reality I need it to compare with what happens in NF where all of those are absent. I still think it's possible, but if this is not possible then it would be also interesting to know a proof of consistency of Z with a counter-example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot prove this even in ZF.  For instance, it is consistent with ZF+DC (in particular, with ZF+"every infinite set is Dedekind-infinite") that there exists an $\aleph_1$-amorphous set, which is a set such that every subset is either countable or cocountable.  Such a set cannot be in bijection with a disjoint union of two copies of itself, since each copy in the disjoint union is uncountable and councountable.

Comment: Derp, I was being silly!